# c++ : Undefined reference to main using g++

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-reference

I've been learning c++ by reading the book 'c++ Primer Plus' by Stephen Prata. In chapter 10 there is an example which has three (Listing 10.4 to 10.6) files (stock10.h (contains the class declaration), stock10.cpp (contains the member function definitions) and usestok1.cpp (contains the calling function)).

When I compile these together using the command

```
g++ -o stock usestok1.cpp stock10.cpp
```

I'm getting the following error

```
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And the file 'usestok1.cpp' vanishes from the working directory. Where have I gone wrong?

The code contained by the files:

First one (stock10.h) has the class declaration.

```
//stock10.h
#ifndef STOCK10_H_
#define STOCK10_H_
#include <string>
class stock
{
    private:
        std::string company;
        long shares;
        double share_val;
        double total_val;
        void set_tot() {total_val = shares*share_val;}
    public:
        stock();
        stock(const std::string& co,long n=0,double pr=0);
        ~stock();
        void buy(long num,double price);
        void sell(long num,double price);
        void update(double price);
        void show();
};
#endif
```

Second one (stock10.cpp) has class member definitions

```
//stock10.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "stock10.h"
stock::stock()
{
    std::cout<<"Default constructor invoked";
    company="no name";
    shares=0;
    share_val=0.0;
    total_val=0.0;
}
stock::stock(const std::string& co,long n,double pr)
{
    std::cout<<"Consturctor using"<<co<<" called\n";
    company=co;
    if(n<0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Number of shares cannot be negative;"<<company<<" shares set to 0.\n";
        shares=0;
    }
    else shares=n;
    share_val=pr;
    set_tot();
}
stock::~stock()
{
    std::cout<<"Bye, "<<company<<"\n";
}
void stock::buy(long num,double price)
{
    if(num<0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Number of shares purchased can't be negative. Transaction is aborted.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        shares+=num;
        share_val=price;
        set_tot();
    }
}
void stock::sell(long num,double price)
{
    using std::cout;
    if(num<0)
    {
        cout<<"Number of shares sold can't be negative. "<<" Transaction is aborted.\n";
    }
    else if(num>shares)
    {
        cout<<"You can't sell any more shares. Transaction is aborted.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        shares-=num;
        share_val=price;
        set_tot();
    }
}
void stock::update(double price)
{
    share_val=price;
    set_tot();
}
void stock::show()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::ios_base;
    using std::endl;
    ios_base::fmtflags orig=cout.setf(ios_base::fixed,ios_base::floatfield);
    std::streamsize prec=cout.precision(3);
    cout<<"Company : "<<company<<endl;
    cout<<"Shares : "<<shares<<endl;
    cout.precision(2);
    cout<<"total Worth : $"<<total_val<<endl;
    cout.setf(orig,ios_base::floatfield);
    cout.precision(prec);
}
```

And the last one (usestok1.cpp) has the calling function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stock10.h"
int main()
{
    {
    using std::cout;
    cout << "Using constructors to create new objects\n";
    stock stock1("NanoSmart", 12, 20.0);
    stock1.show();
    stock stock2 = stock ("Boffo Objects", 2, 2.0); // syntax 2
    stock2.show();
    cout << "Assigning stock1 to stock2:\n";
    stock2 = stock1;
    cout << "Listing stock1 and stock2:\n";
    stock1.show();  
    stock2.show();
    cout << "Using a constructor to reset an object\n";
    stock1 = stock("Nifty Foods", 10, 50.0);
    cout << "Revised stock1:\n";
    stock1.show();
    cout << "Done\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the information you have supplied that will explain the symptom you are seeing.   There is probably some other information, that you have deemed irrelevant and not posted here, that is the real cause of the problem.

Comment: The compiler says it cannot find your `main` function. You probably compiled the wrong file or didn't save it after editing.

Comment: @Peter missing information such as?

Comment: _And the file 'usestok1.cpp' vanishes from the working directory._ I've never seen a compiler delete source files before, I suspect your problem might be path related.

Comment: @iambrj - well, let's see.   Is the command performed from command line, a script, or an IDE setting?   Were there any error messages or warnings from the compiler?  (the only error message you've described is from the linker, not the compiler).   What environment or path settings?  What operating system?    The point is: you're the one with the problem, and you have almost certainly deemed some things you're doing, or with your setup, as not relevant to the problem - and other people can only guess what those things are.